# Issues While Trying To Recreate SwiftUI-based App From WWDC Session

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to recreate the SwiftUI project demonstrated in Session 204  but am running into some peculiar issues.

I wrote this from watching the session found here: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/204

Here is my code-

ContentView.swift:

```swift
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView : View {
    @ObjectBinding var store = RoomStore()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section {
                    Button(action: addRoom) {
                        Text("Add Room")
                    }
                }

                Section {

                    ForEach(store.rooms) { room in //Error: Cannot convert value of type '(Room) -> RoomCell' to expected argument type '(_) -> _'
                        RoomCell(room: room)
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: delete)
                    .onMove(perform: move)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Rooms") )
            .NavigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
            .listStyle(.grouped)
        }
    }

    func addRoom() {
        store.rooms.append(Room(name: "Hall 2", capacity: 2000))
    }
    func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        store.rooms.remove(atOffsets: offsets) //Error: Incorrect argument label in call (have 'atOffsets:', expected 'at:')
    }
    func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
        store.rooms.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination) //Error: Value of type '[Room]' has no member 'move'; did you mean 'remove'?
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            ContentView(store: RoomStore(rooms: testData))
            ContentView(store: RoomStore(rooms: testData))
            .environment(\.sizeCategory, .extraExtraExtraLarge)
            ContentView(store: RoomStore(rooms: testData))
            .environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)
            ContentView(store: RoomStore(rooms: testData))
            .environment(\.layoutDirection, .rightToLeft)
            .environment(\.locale, Locale(identifier: "ar"))
        }
    }
}
#endif
struct RoomCell : View {
    let room: Room
    var body: some View {
        return NavigationButton(destination: RoomDetail(room: room) )
        {
            Image(room.thumbnailName)
            .cornerRadius(8)
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text (room.name)
                Text ("\(room.capacity) peopje")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Room.swift:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Room {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var capacity: Int
    var hasVideo: Bool = false
    var imageName: String { return name }
    var thumbnailName: String { return name + "Thumb" }

}

#if DEBUG

let testData = [
    Room(name: "Observation Deck", capacity: 6, hasVideo: true),
    Room(name: "Executive Suite", capacity: 8, hasVideo: false),
    Room(name: "Charter Jet", capacity: 16, hasVideo: true),
    Room(name: "Dungeon", capacity: 10, hasVideo: true),
    Room(name: "Panorama", capacity: 12, hasVideo: false),
    Room(name: "Oceanfront", capacity: 8, hasVideo: false),
    Room(name: "Rainbow Room", capacity: 10, hasVideo: true),
    Room(name: "Pastoral", capacity: 7, hasVideo: false),
    Room(name: "Elephant Room", capacity: 1, hasVideo: false),

]

#endif
```

RoomDetail.swift:

```swift
import SwiftUI
struct RoomDetail : View {
    let room: Room
    @State private var zoomed = false
    var body: some View { //Error: Function declares an opaque return type, but has no return statements in its body from which to infer an underlying type
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            Image(room.imageName )
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: zoomed ? .fill : .fit)
                .navigationBarTitle(Text(room.name), displayMode:
                    .inline)
                .tapAction { withAnimation(.basic(duration: 2)) {
                    self.zoomed.toggle() } }
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight:
                0, maxHeight: .infinity)
            if room.hasVideo && !zoomed {
                Image(systemName: "video. fill")
                    .font(.title)
                    .padding(.all)
                    .transition(.move(edge: .leading) )
            }
        }
}

#if DEBUG
struct RoomDetail_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            NavigationView { RoomDetail(room: testData[0]) }
            NavigationView { RoomDetail(room: testData[1]) }
        }
}
}
#endif
```

RoomStore.swift:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class RoomStore : BindableObject {
    var rooms: [Room] {
        didSet { didChange.send(Void()) } //Solved
    }
    init(rooms: [Room] = []) {
        self.rooms = rooms
    }
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
}
```

Error messages included in context, as comments, in above code.

Comment: You can safely write `()` rather than `Void()`, as `Void` is defined like this in Swift: `public typealias Void = ()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For this error: **//Error: Cannot convert value of type '(Room) -> RoomCell' to expected argument type '(_) -> _'**
Implement Identifiable protocol to your list model like this,

```
struct Room: Identifiable
```

For this one: **//Error: Incorrect argument label in call (have 'atOffsets:', expected 'at:')**
I think it is not your problem :) But you can use something like this,

```
guard let index = Array(offset).first else { return }
store.rooms.remove(at: index)
```

And for this one:  **//Error: Value of type '[Room]' has no member 'move'; did you mean 'remove'?** As before, you can use that piece of code for moving

```
guard let sourceIndex = Array(source).first else { return }
store.rooms.insert(roomStore.rooms.remove(at: sourceIndex), at: destination)
```

You can check completed source code,
https://github.com/ilyadaberdil/iOS-Samples/tree/master/SwiftUI-Sample

Answer (score 3):

Did you try passing Void()?

```
class RoomStore : BindableObject {
    var rooms: [Room] {
        didSet { didChange.send(Void()) } 
    }
    init(rooms: [Room] = []) {
        self.rooms = rooms
    }
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In **Xcode 11 beta 4**

> The **BindableObject** protocol’s requirement is now `willChange` instead of `didChange`, and should now be sent before the object changes rather than after it changes. This change allows for improved coalescing of change notifications.

```
class RoomStore: BindableObject {

    var rooms: [Room] {
        didSet { willChange.send() }
    }

    init(rooms: [Room] = []) {
        self.rooms = rooms
    }

    var willChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
}
```

For deleting and moving, use below code.

```
func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    store.rooms.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
}

func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
    store.rooms.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Rooms` has to be `@Published`

```
class RoomStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var rooms: [Room] {
        didSet {
            willChange.send()
        }
    }

    init(rooms: [Room] = []) {
        self.rooms = rooms
    }

   var willChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use `Room` in your `List`, you have to implement the `Identifiable` protocol. I forgot it too and the SwiftUI error message:

> Cannot convert value of type '(Room) -> RoomCell' to expected argument type '(_) -> _'

is not helpful.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Room: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID() 
    ...
}
```

Comment: This fixes the issue, but on run the screen is blank and the console displays instances of "ProjectName[5100:331150] -[UIWindow beginDisablingInterfaceAutorotation] overflow on <UIWindow: 0x7ff6ecf05ca0; frame = (0 0; 414 896); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x6000038aea00>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x6000036e18c0>>. Ignoring."

Comment: Found the issue. I was missing a dot before listStyle.

Answer (score 0):

For deleting and moving you can use something like this:

```
func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    offsets.sorted { $0 > $1 }.forEach { store.rooms.remove(at: $0) }
}

func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
    source.sorted { $0 > $1 }.forEach { store.rooms.insert(store.rooms.remove(at: $0), at: destination) }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

According to https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input section 4, step 2, the PassthroughSubject should take the type of the class you're binding, not Void. So it would seem to be more correct (and works).

```
var didChange = PassthroughSubject<RoomStore, Never>()
```

As for the delete and move functions, since Swift 5.1 arrays have neither a move nor a remove(atOffsets:) method I can only assume they forgot to remove some custom extensions to Array. I could find no mention of those functions on Swift Evolution either.

Here's hoping they just forgot to tell us they're coming in a later release.

:) Teo

Comment: PassthroughSubject can take any type, including Void. Here we want to sigle the view to refresh its body, we don't need to whole self or any other object for that matter